# Spring MVC, Form Submission not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Can some one help me with this?

My Controller class looks like this, and i have created the customer model class..

```
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView student() {
        return new ModelAndView("customer", "command", new Customer());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, 
       ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("customerName", customer.getCustomerName());
        model.addAttribute("emailId", customer.getEmailId());
        model.addAttribute("sex", customer.getSex());

        return "customerDetails";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Customer Form Handling</display-name>


    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Customer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/Customer/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Customer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

JSP Pages

customer.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Customer Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" commandName = "command" action="/addCustomer">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="customerName">customerName</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="customerName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="emailId">emailId</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="sex">sex</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="sex" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

customerDetails.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Customer Detail Information</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>CustomerName</td>
        <td>${customerName}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>emailId</td>
        <td>${emailId}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sex</td>
        <td>${sex}</td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet-Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <!-- <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.customerinfo.controller" />

</beans:beans>
```

But when I run this application in Tomcat Server.. The first url points to
`localhost:8080/controller/`.

If I append `localhost:8080/controller/customer` I get the first form page..

But once I click on submit.. it says page not found error.

Comment: Is your customerDetails view in the directory /WEB-INF/views. Or is there a directory inbetween like customer?

Comment: Its inside WEB-INF/views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a relative path problem. Your form action is `/addCustomer` (has `/` prefix), if you resolve it it's `http://localhost:8080/addCustomer`. What you wanted is probably `http://localhost:8080/appname/customer/addCustomer`.

In some cases simply changing it into `customer/addCustomer` might resolve it, but if your page can also be accessed by `http://localhost:8080/appname/customer/` (pay attention to the trailing slash) then this could be a problem. The relative path will translate into `http://localhost:8080/appname/customer/customer/addCustomer`

Of course now you can think to just do `/appname/customer/addCustomer` and problem solved, but in fact you are now hard-coding the context path name. If one day the context path changes all this code will break.

One approach I like to use so my JSP can figure out the context path is by defining a root variable

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
...
<form:form action="${root}/customer/addCustomer">
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. When i changed the action to customer/addcustomer it resolved the issue. I am not able to understand these... When i run the application on tomcat server. I mean i run the application from eclipse. So i right click on the project and run on server. The initial Page gets loaded as http://localhost:8080/controller/ and it says page not loaded. Then if i change the Url to http://localhost:8080/controller/customer the first page which i intended works and i get the form page. How to correct it. And also y should the action be referred as customer/addcustomer.

Comment: Because /customer is the path your controller is mapped to and /addcustomer is the path the handler method is mapped to

Answer (score 2):

try as

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName = "command" action="addCustomer">
```

instead of

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName = "command" action="/addCustomer">
```